# Kicked after message not working for discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Heres my code

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['k', 'boot'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = "No Reason Provided"):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    print("Kicked " + str(member))
    await member.send("You have been kicked")
    await ctx.send("**Kicked " + member + " (" + reason + ")**")
```

The kicking itself, works fine, the problem is the `await ctx.send("**Kicked " + str(member) + " (" + reason + ")**")` doesn't work for some reason. In the Google searches I've done, it seems to be working for everyone but not for me. Sending messages works fine for other commands but not this one. I've tried making the member variable into a string, I've tried using F strings, it just doesn't work. Also, if it makes a difference, the person I'm kicking to test this, is another bot.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.command(aliases = ['k', 'boot'])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = "No Reason Provided"):
    await member.kick(reason = reason)
    print("Kicked " + str(member))
    await member.send("You have been kicked")
    await ctx.send("**Kicked " + str(member) + " (" + reason + ")**")
```

you forgot to str the member at the last send if you don't do that you get an error because you cant add to str a Member object

Comment: I don't get an error, it just doesn't do anything also I've tried this already.

Comment: well this works for me... try maybe to update discord.py or give the intents to your bot

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it got me thinking and I solved my problem, I'll be posting the answer shortly.

Comment: By the way, you can add a member object and string object togethor with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

In order to send a message to anyone who doesn't have the perms to a command, I added this piece of code.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the perms to do that")
```

The problem is that this solves the perms error but every other error doesn't print. After finding this I changed the code to the following.

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have perms to do that")
    else:
        print(ctx, error)
```

This printed my error, my bot sends messages to every user kicked to notify them, when I was testing this, I was kicking another bot and DMs cannot be sent to bots, so I added this line of code to my `member.send("You have been kicked")` line.

```
if not member.bot:
    await member.send("You have been kicked")
```

This solved my problem and the bot works now.